# Stop React server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, server, command-line, localhost

I closed the terminal where my react app was running.How do I now stop the server?

I tried deleting the folder but it says that it is open in an another program(i closed all the folders).tried running the app once again but it didnt work? Please help.

Comment: You can kill the pid process, or just log out and relogin of your computer

Comment: try closing it through Task manager is the session is still running on background.